# SSIS Get Columns of Two Different SharePoint Lists

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to get two columns but each one of them are in differents SharePoint Lists.

Is it possible to get these columns and put it into a single destination? I'll need to use both later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use SSIS [this article](http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/) gives detailed instructions on how to get information from a sharepoint list.  Once you have set up the sharepoint data sources to get the single column from the lists.  Then point the data flow out to a Union All component, this will allow you to combine the two desperate data flows into on data flow (see attached picture).  Then you can connect the single data flow to data destination, in the case of the picture it is a SQL server table.

If you do not have access to SSIS it is possible to do extract the data directly from the SQL tables if you have access to the sharepoint database.  Not an approach that l would recommend.

[image: Two data sources from share point list to a union all to single SQL data destination]